# Pyspark collecting/grouping nested data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with research papers metadata in spark 2.4.5 Example is:
[image: dataframe picture]
which I need to group on `auid` and collect associated `eids`, `affiliation ids` (from affiliation column), `affiliation cities` (which I join from other df, as this df is patchy), to later track affiliation city changes over time. So at the end, probably I neeed `auid` and a struct of `eid`, `year`, `affil_id`, `aff_city`.
I tried few things, but not quite happy with the result, so am asking for support here. If needed, I can post df sample in text form.

Comment: could you share what you tried?

Comment: yes, you should add some text samples and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

that worked:

```
df.groupBy('auid').agg(func.collect_set(func.struct('eid', 'Year', 'affiliation.affiliation_organization', 'affiliation.affiliation_city', 'affiliation.afid')).alias('eid_attr_set'))
```